# Nginx seems to double size of URI (path+query) when sending to uWsgi

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, nginx-config

Using Nginx over uWsgi with the default protocol (presumably uwsgi):

- When you send a request with a long path thru Nginx, say 4k characters,
  uWsgi then reports a buffer of size about 8k.
- Same for a short path with a long query parameter.
- When you send a header variable with size 4k, this is not the case.

Why the difference? What is Nginx doing to cause this?

The end result of this is that you need to double the `buffer-size` / `-b` argument  in uWsgi to match the `large_client_header_buffers` value in Nginx.

Before I do this, I would like to know why this is the case, perhaps I can avoid it with some other weird configuration in Nginx (like `pointlessly_duplicate_the_path=False`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was because someone snuck in a pair of `uwsgi_param` settings when I wasn't looking, to send `$request_uri` and `$query_string` to uWsgi as separate variables.

In short: if you do this, do realize that you are at risk of violating your `buffer-size` settings (if you don't take the fact that you're doubling up the URL)